# How to modify Faraday middleware configuration on a per-request basis?

Tags: ruby, faraday

I've got some well-configured Faraday client:

```
client = Faraday.new(url: base_url) do |f|
  f.request :retry, { max: 3, backoff_factor: 2 }
  f.request :authorization, 'Bearer', -> { access_token }
  f.request :json
  f.response :json
  f.response :raise_error
end
```

and for the most part it's great, but now I've got this one weird case where I want to retry on an apparently successful request because I'm waiting for data to propagate, so I want to do something like:

```
client(
 retry_options: {
   max: 10,
   retry_if: -> (env, _exc) { 
     env.body[:data][:ready] == false
   }
).get("/wait-for-data")
```

The idea being that for *this specific request*, I want to modify the existing configuration for the retry middleware, so that it'll "fail", and retry with the backoff many more times.

I'm not finding anything, but I'm also getting pretty poor Google results looking for insight. Can anyone point me at some ways to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you get any new insights in the last 4 months?

Comment: Not really. I didn't find ways to modify the middleware on a per-request basis. The "best" I could figure out was to just create a differently configured client, and use (one of many) forms of dependency injection to use that client for that request. What exactly that looks like is going to depend *heavily* on how, exactly, you're using the returned client.